# document.write a new page with a unified font-size across the page

Tags: javascript, inline-styles

I want to open a new page that has content identical to a `div` called `Div1` in the old page.
In my JavaScript function I have a `newWindow` variable that is returned by a `window.open` command, and I write the inner HTML of `Div1` into `newWindow`, and I want every single text within the new page has a font size of 7px. Here is what I wrote:

```
newWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Hello World</title>');
        newWindow.document.write('</head><body style="font-size:7px">');
        newWindow.document.write($('Div1').html());
        newWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
```

The new page renders but since the content in `Div1` are splited into 3 `fieldset`s, only the `legend`s of those `fieldset`s have their font size changed to 7px, everything within the fieldsets still has default font size (which is approximately 11px). How to change every text in the new page to 7px? I can `document.write` a link to a new stylesheet for the new page but I prefer inline styling. Thanks.

---

Old page (ASP.net):

```
<div id="Div1" runat=server>
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="LLegends"> Header </legend>
            <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server">
                contents that I want to be 7px in the new page
            </asp:FormView>
     </fieldset>

     <!-- other 2 fieldsets with the same set up -->
</div>
```

Class `LLegends` (only class of elements that has CSS style)

```
.LLegends {font-size: large;}
```

Comment: You'd have to show us the actual HTML involved here.  If some of the HTML tags have their own `font-size` inline style settings or are inheriting styles from a style sheet with higher CSS precedence, then your style on the `<body>` tag won't override those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot do inline styling on the new page's `body` but I figure I can change

```
newWindow.document.write('</head><body style="font-size:7px">');
```

To:

```
newWindow.document.write('<style>.body {"font-size:7px"}</style></head><body>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snippet. Add your actual styles, then append them to the document with your other HTML.
SO is preventing the new window from opening, so try this url: http://output.jsbin.com/sobewavagi

```js
    (function(undefined) {
      /**
       *
       */
      'use strict';

      function addStyleOnOpen() {
        var style,
          stylesheet,
          pageTitle = 'my title',

          prnt = open();

        style = document.createElement("style");

        style.setAttribute('media', 'all');
        style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
        style.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');

        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
        prnt.document.head.appendChild(style);

        stylesheet = style.sheet;

        stylesheet.insertRule('body {width: 100% !important;margin: 0 !important;padding: 0 !important;line-height: 1.45;font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;color: #999;background: none;font-size: 14pt;}', 0);

        stylesheet.insertRule('#new-window {color: green;}', stylesheet.cssRules.length);

        stylesheet.insertRule('h1 {color: red;}', stylesheet.cssRules.length);

        prnt.document.title = pageTitle;
        prnt.document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '\n <h1>Heading</h1> \n <p id="new-window">Hello World!</p>');
      }

      document.getElementById('new-window').addEventListener('click', addStyleOnOpen, false);


    }(undefined));
```

```html
<a href="#" id="new-window">Open</a>
```

Comment: I noticed, SO did not open the window for me. I will update the snippet.